# Image of $C^\ast$-algebra is closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a non-zero commutative $C^\ast$ algebra and let $\varphi : A \to B$ be a homomorphism of star algebras.

Please could someone help me how to show that $\varphi(A)$ is closed in $B$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that $\varphi $ is a $*$-homomorphism implies that $\bar\varphi:A/\ker\varphi\to\varphi (A) $, given by $\bar\varphi (a+\ker\varphi)=\varphi (a) $, is isometric and onto.

So any Cauchy sequence in $\varphi (A) $ comes from a Cauchy sequence in $ A/\ker\varphi $. As the latter is closed (in general the quotient of a Banach space by a Banach subspace is closed), so is $\varphi (A) $.

**Edit:** suppose that $\varphi:A\to B$ is  isometric. Let $\{b_n\}\subset\varphi(A)$ be Cauchy. We have $b_n=\varphi(a_n)$ for appropriate $a_n\in A$. Since $$\|b_n-b_m\|=\|\varphi(a_n)-\varphi(a_m)\|=\|\varphi(a_n-a_m)\|=\|a_n-a_m\|,$$ we deduce that $\{a_n\}$ is Cauchy. With $A$ complete, there exists $a\in A$ with $a=\lim a_n$. As $\varphi$ is continuous, $\varphi(a)=\lim\varphi(a_n)=\lim b_n$. So $\varphi(A)$ is complete.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Is it clear that $A / \mathrm{ker}\varphi$ is closed? (I'm asking because it's not clear to me)

Comment: The quotient of a Banach space by a Banach subspace is Banach. Easiest reference I can think of is Conway, III.4.2.

Comment: I'm sorry, I knew that but somehow didn't make the connection from "contains all its limit points=closed" to "complete if and only if it contains all its limit points". Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Wait but does this argument really work? If you have an isometric isometry from $[0,1]$ to $(0,1)$ wouldn't it map the sequence ${1\over n}$ to a Cauchy sequence converging to $0$? (I know this particular example doesn't work but what I want to say is: if you have an isometry mapping Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequence, why does the limit point it maps to have to be in the image?)

Comment: The image of a linear isometry is closed. See the edit.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Can you elaborate the case of a nonunital C*-algebra, plase?

Comment: @MartinArgerami what about Banach algebras. Can an injective Banach algebra morphism have a non closed image?

Comment: Yes, even if it is bounded. For example consider the identity map $\ell^1(\mathbb N)\to\ell^2(\mathbb N)$.